# monaco editor + angular, editor not recognizing languages properly

Tags: angular, typescript, monaco-editor

Using angular and monaco-editor and the editor being created from this angular component does not color in, or complete "key" words in java such as int, double, etc.. I have tried so many things at this point and am wondering if the issue is with how monaco is interacting with angular or what. The style is not getting altered for some reason.

```
declare var require: any;
import { NgModule, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, ViewChild, Input, ElementRef, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import 'script-loader!../../../../node_modules/monaco-editor/dev/vs/editor/editor.main';
import  {registerLanguage} from 'script-loader!../../../../node_modules/monaco-editor/dev/vs/basic-languages/_.contribution';
import {conf} from 'script-loader!../../../../node_modules/monaco-editor/dev/vs/basic-languages/java/java.js';


export class ZoeComponent implements IComponent {
  capabilities: Array<Capability>;
  element: HTMLElement;
  constructor(inputCapabilities: Array<Capability>, inputEl: HTMLElement) {
    this.element = inputEl;
    this.capabilities = inputCapabilities.slice(0);
  }
  getDOMElement(): HTMLElement {
    return this.element;
  }
  getCapabilities(): Capability[] {
    return this.capabilities;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'zlux-editor-window',
  templateUrl: 'zlux-editor-window.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['zlux-editor-window.component.css',
    '../../../../node_modules/monaco-editor/dev/vs/editor/editor.main.css']
})
export class ZluxEditorWindowComponent implements ComponentFactory {
  @ViewChild('editor') editorContent: ElementRef;
  editorEle: HTMLElement;
  componentClass: ComponentClass;
  capabilities: Array<Capability>;
  inputContents: fileContents = { filePath: '/u/ts6223/', fileName: 'hello.txt', fileContents: ['hi', "i'm", "right here!"] };

  constructor() {
    this.componentClass = ComponentClass.CodeEditor;
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {

    var onGotAmdLoader = () => {

        this.initMonaco(this.inputContents.fileContents);

    };
    onGotAmdLoader();



  }
  initMonaco(inputContents: Array<string>) {
    this.editorEle = this.editorContent.nativeElement;
    let x =monaco.editor.create(this.editorEle, {
      value: inputContents
        .join('\n'),
      language: 'java',
      quickSuggestions: { other: true, comments: true, strings: true }


    }).layout({ width: 500, height: 800 });
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ZluxEditorWindowComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [ZluxEditorWindowComponent],
  entryComponents: [ZluxEditorWindowComponent]
})
export class ZluxEditorWindowModule { }
```

Is there anything within the monaco sections that seems to be off?

--